# scroll with to section using keyboard

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to allow scroll using keyboard arrows, the issue is that its smooth going downwards but not upwards. I also want it to scroll to each section instead of holding down the arrow. is this possible?

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 38: // up
      document.body.scrollTop -= 500;
      document.documentElement.scrollTop -= 500;
      break;

    case 40: // down
      document.body.scrollDown += 500;
      document.documentElement.scrollDown += 500;
      break;

    default:
      return; // exit this handler for other keys
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  window.focus();
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To animate scrolling to specific element, you can do this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#section-1").offset().top
}, 1e3); // 1sec
```

To find currently visible section, you could iterate over them and check it like this:

```
var $current = null;

$('.section').each(function() {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(this).height();

    if (!$current && elemBottom <= docViewBottom && elemTop >= docViewTop) {
        $current = $(this);
    }
});
```

Then based on pressed key, select next or previous element via `$.next()` or `$.prev()` and use it when scrolling:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $current.next().offset().top
}, 1e3); // 1sec
```

Here is a working plunker (still some bugs there, just a prove of concept):

https://plnkr.co/edit/GMVKhskBn2mt3OXiCRo6?p=preview

Comment: if you try to scroll up it still moves down

Comment: Should be fixed now, but as I said, there can be still bugs, this is not a free coding service, you should do the job on your own, I am just trying to get you on the right direction.